VS Code Debug Extension: Problem to get the vscode-mock-debug project running
I wanted to follow the steps in Development Setup For Mock Debug. After I run the Extension launcher (F5) there were plently errors being thrown in my face:
Error 1:

Error 2:

Therefore, debugging the readme.md in the Extension Development Host window was not possible as it printed the following error message:
Activating extension 'ms-vscode.mock-debug' failed: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\john\Documents\vscode-mock-debug\dist\extension.js'

Require stack:
- c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js


Solution: In case some folks out there had the same problems, here is what I have done to get it running:

install the VS Code extension ESLint from Microsoft
start the Powershell as admin and type in the following command:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser 

